# how can I convert a constat value into a non constant variable?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
   PARAMS Params;
   Params.pwchFileName = wide.c_str() ;
```

But I a getting this error:

```
    a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "wchar_t *"
```

How can make this assignment?

Answer (score 3):

You could, with extreme caution, use a `const_cast`:

`const_cast<wchar_t*>( wide.c_str());`

But the are other issues here: if `wide` is a `std::string` then the results of `c_str()` are only valid for as long as `wide` is in scope and has not been changed in any way. Even if you conform to this, then a consumer of `PARAMS` *could* modify the string buffer which would give you *undefined behaviour*.

The best thing to do here is to use `strcpy` to take a deep copy of the string buffer, remembering to `delete` that buffer once you're done with it.

Answer (score 2):

The only way of making a non-constant value from a constant one that would be safe in all contexts is to make a copy:

```
Params.pwchFileName = new char[wide.size()+1];
strcpy(Params.pwchFileName, wide.c_str());
...
// when you are done with the copy, delete it:
delete[] Params.pwchFileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it forcefully by casting away constness using :-

```
Params.pwchFileName = const_cast<wchar_t*>( wide.c_str() );
```

But use const_cast when you have no other choice.

Be careful, writing into that object invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `wide` is `std::wstring`.

If `wide` is const, you have to use `const_cast<wchar_t*>(wide.c_str())`.

However, if it is not const, you can and should avoid the `const_cast`.
If you are using C++17 or newer, you can use `wide.data()` instead. (`data` does the same as `c_str`, but since C++17 it has a not-const-classified overload which `c_str` does not).
Before C++17 you can use `&wide[0]` as a workaround.